# Why does NetBeans and Android Studio behave differently on my code?

Tags: java, android, netbeans

So i got this situation where i need to add a certain amount of weeks to a date and put out the result date. Here is my code:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date startDate = new Date();
    int addWeeks = 2;
    cal.setTime(startDate);
    int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int endWeek = week + addWeeks;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, endWeek);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    Date endDate = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(endDate.toString());
```

When i implement that in the Netbeans IDE (8.01), it works totally fine (output: 15 feb 2016..) but when i run it inside an android application (API 23) with android studio the result is 01 feb 2016. Also couldn't solve the problem through debugging and checked the imports. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `java.util.Date` is, generally speaking, a _terrible_ API that you should avoid using at all costs.  It has so much poorly specified bad behavior that it doesn't surprise me at all that Android gets different results.  Use Joda Time if at all possible.